# How To Calculate Binomial Distribution Of Really Small %?

Tags: probability, statistics, binomial-distribution

I asked [this question on the Bitcoin Forum](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/76977/number-of-trials-required-for-brute-force-attack-to-have-x-of-success), but I think it's more appropriate for a mathematics forum.

I'm making an informative video and I need a binomial distribution calculation. I want to find out how many trials are needed to get 1%, 50% and 90% likelihood 1 or more successes. The problem is that the likelihood of success is **1 out of 2^160** (number of distinct bitcoin/ethereum addresses).

Normally for something like this, I would use a [binomial distribution calculation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/binom-dist-function-c5ae37b6-f39c-4be2-94c2-509a1480770c) in Excel using this formula:

`=1-BINOM.DIST(0,????,2^-160,TRUE)`

I would then tinker with the `????` until the entire cell result returned 1%, 50% and 90%. However, Excel can't handle numbers anywhere near this large. Does anyone know of a way I can calculate the number of trials required for these 3 percentages given the infinitesimally small chance of success? It would be great if there was an online tool I could use to support my results.

Just to illustrate what I'm looking for. If this analysis was for something much simpler, such as a probability of success being `1%`, then I could calculate the results to be:

- **229** trials needed for 90%, | 89.99%`=1-BINOM.DIST(0,229,0.01,TRUE)`
- **69** trials needed for 50%,  | 50.01%`=1-BINOM.DIST(0,69,0.01,TRUE)`
- **1** trial needed for 1%,  | 1.00%`=1-BINOM.DIST(0,1,0.01,TRUE)`

Comment: Solution: don't use Excel. Use a language that can give you more digits, say, Python.

Comment: In R you can use  `pbinom(0,???,2^(-160), FALSE)`

Comment: Why the binomial distribution, which assumes you may sample the same address again ("with replacement")?  Wouldn't one only test addresses that one has not already tested?  I.e., the rational choice would be to sequentially test addresses, which would lead to 50% confidence of successful finding after scanning 50% of the address space.

Comment: @EricTowers, good question and I commented in your answer, but I'll comment here too. Each bitcoin private key (2^256 possible) generates a random result of an address. Stated differently, each private key has an equal chance of returning any of the 2^160 addresses available. Thus, each trial should be treated as an independent event (binomial distribution), even if we've eliminated half of the potential private keys.

Comment: @SeanRoberson if you post a python solution, I will upvote it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using manual tinkering with R I get the following values

```
pbinom(0,3.365231884e48,2^(-160), FALSE)   = 0.9000000000339017
pbinom(0,1.0130357393e48,2^(-160), FALSE)  = 0.5000000000001161
pbinom(0,1.46885823057e46,2^(-160), FALSE) = 0.01000000000005571
```

As a check

```
pbinom(0,229,0.01, FALSE) = 0.8998941257385102
pbinom(0,69,0.01, FALSE)  = 0.5001629701008011
pbinom(0,1,0.01, FALSE)   = 0.01
```

Comment: @ParclyTaxel this actually would imply the opposite. It's much more profitable to mine than to try to steal people's coins through brute force attacks on their addresses.

Comment: thanks @gammatester! what is R I? Python?

Comment: @PGCodeRider See https://www.r-project.org/ and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_(programming_language)

Comment: @PGCodeRider it would technically be "...with R, I get". R and Python are both programming languages that have a decent catalog of mathematical functions available.

Answer (score 12):

Letting $p$ be the probability of success on one trial, and letting $T$ be the desired probability that you want to exceed (for at least one success in $n$ trials), we need
$$1-(1-p)^n>T$$
This can be rewritten as $(1-p)^n<1-T$.

So we want $n\ln(1-p)<\ln(1-T)$

Which is equivalent to $n>\frac{\ln(1-T)}{\ln(1-p)}$

If $p$ is very small you get a very good approximation to $\ln(1-p)$ with a degree one Taylor approximation: $\ln(1-p)\approx -p$. (The next term of the Taylor approximation will be $\frac{-p^2}{2}$ which can probably be considered negligible; and the overall error will also be around this value.)

So you would want $n$ to be around $\frac{\ln(1-T)}{-p}$

In the case of $p=2^{-160}$, this gives $n > -2^{160}\cdot \ln(1-T)$

Comment: Thanks for the detailed analysis. I gave @gammetester the acceptance, but I marked your as helpful.

Comment: [The Law of Rare Events](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Law_of_rare_events) (a.k.a. Law of Small Numbers) says that for large $n$ and small $p$, Binom($n$,$p$) is approximately Poisson($np$).  This gives another way to arrive at your expression for $n$.

Comment: @Teepeemm Nice observation!

Answer (score 3):

I observe that $229/0.01^{-1} \approx 3.36\times 10^{48}/\left(2^{-160}\right)^{-1}$, so I believe [@gammatester's numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2845653/123905).  What I don't believe is that we have to search $229\%$ of the address space to be only $90\%$ confident to find the one address for which we search.

(More precisely, $\log_2 3.365231884 \times 10^{48} = 161.203\dots$, which is $2.302\dots$-times the size of your address space.)

The process you describe with this binomial distribution is randonly picking an address, testing it, then placing it back into the population of addresses that may be picked in the future.  A substantially more efficient method is to sequentially check addresses -- meaning that we are $100\%$ certain to have found the address after checking $100\%$ of the address space.  In fact, we are $1\%$ certain after checking $1\%$ of the space, $50\%$ after $50\%$, and so on.

Comment: Thanks @Eric, I marked your answer as helpful, however the address space private key combinations is not 2^160 (this is a common misunderstanding even among Bitcoin enthusiasts). Because Bitcoin uses the secp256k1, the private key space is essentially 2^256 and we are getting random results (as far as we can tell). Thus each calculation is an independent event not changing the liklihood of future success. So technically, there is no absolute guarantee that an address will even have a private key. However, since we have an allocated amount of 2^96 private keys available, it's pretty likely.

Comment: @PGCodeRider : So we're actually only searching through a known set of $2^{96}$ keys?

Comment: incorrect. 2^96 represents how many private keys would exist for every public key if they were EVENLY distributed. However, there's no way to tell what private keys align with what public address, so the space to search remains at  2^256.

Answer (score 2):

The 'bc' unix utility can be used to find the number of minimum trials using paw88789's formula :

> $n > \ln(1−T) / \ln(1−p).$

```
#!/bin/sh
bc -l <<EOF |
scale=1000

p=1/(2^(160))

t= 1; print  t, "/100: minimum trials needed "; l(1-t/100)/l(1-p); print "|\n";
t=50; print  t, "/100: minimum trials needed "; l(1-t/100)/l(1-p); print "|\n";
t=90; print  t, "/100: minimum trials needed "; l(1-t/100)/l(1-p); print "|\n";

EOF
tr -d '\\\n'|tr '|' '\n'|sed 's@\..*@@'
```

$ sh ./2845598

```
1/100: minimum trials needed 14688582305617833934466621173201888921196164071
50/100: minimum trials needed 1013035739299659071135698605846798551586536899366
90/100: minimum trials needed 3365231883504527125129111981421568120141379515366
```

Answer (score 1):

For a $\text{bin}(n,p)$, $P(0\text{ successes}) = (1-p)^n$

To have a $q= 0.01, 0.50$ and $0.99$ chance of 1 or more successes you would correspondingly have $1-q$ -- i.e. $0.99, 0.50$ and $0.01$ chances of 0 successes (complementary probabilities of the complementary event).

For  $P(0\text{ successes}) = 1-q$ we set $1-q = (1-p)^n$, or $n=\log(1-q)/\log(1-p)$ (for any base of logs you like). I'll work with natural logs.

Now $\log(1-p)\approx -p = -2^{-160}$ (to a high degree of accuracy, so we have $n\approx 2^{160}\log(\frac{1}{1-q})$.

Now for $q=0.01, 0.5$ and $0.99$, $\log(\frac{1}{1-q}) \approx 0.01005, 0.69315$ and $4.60517$

More generally for very small $p$, you need $n\approx \frac{1}{p}\log(\frac{1}{1-q})$. You might try it for say $2^{-16}$, for which it's still reasonably accurate; it's much more accurate for very small $p$.

So (calculating in R):

```
n <- (2^16)*log(1/(1-c(.01,.5,.99)))
> n
[1]    658.6588  45426.0936 301804.4333

(1-(2^-16))^n
[1] 0.989999924 0.499997356 0.009999649
```

or since we can't have $n$ being fractional, if we truncate:

```
(1-(2^-16))^trunc(n)
[1] 0.990009876 0.499998070 0.009999715
```

These give essentially the $1-q$ values we required.